# ShareKit Facebook/Twitter logout is not fully working

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter

This is a urgent question to be answered quickly.
I'm developing iPhone application to share the images to social networks.
I'm using ShareKit 2.0 library to implement sharing functions.
I could implement sharing functions perfectly using this and I recommend to use ShareKit library to implement sharing on your app.

The problem is only on Facebook/Twitter logout.
When I wanted to logout from them, I used codes such as following.

```
[SHKFacebook logout];
[SHKTwitter logout];
```

Or I used

```
[SHK logoutOfAll];
```

But I couldn't fully logged out from them, and when I tried to share the images to them, they said "You are logging into this app as XXX" and only asked to confirm this.
Whereas when I removed the app from the iPhone/iPad, they required mail address and password to login again.

I think that is not a big problem to experienced and talented developer.
Please help me.
I'm waiting your advices.

Thanks.
Pei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

facebook cannot logout because all cookies of facebook is not deleted in logout method.

make change in invalidateSession method  in facebook.m file as below:

```
- (void)invalidateSession {
     self.accessToken = nil;
     self.expirationDate = nil;

     NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in cookies.cookies){
        if([cookie.domain rangeOfString:@"facebook"].location != NSNotFound){
            [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
   }

   // setting to nil also terminates any active request for whitelist
   [_frictionlessRequestSettings updateRecipientCacheWithRecipients:nil]; 
}
```

it will delete all cookies of facebook.and logout will work.

Answer (score 0):

In ShareKit 2.0 you have to logout by going facebook page because it works for single time login. It means you have login only one time and it remains login till you logout from facebook page in iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution of them after hard researching.
Problem is on authorize method of Facebook.m of the ShareKit library.

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
    self.permissions = permissions;

    [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];
}
```

Above means that will authorize to Facebook not using Safari.
When users log out from Facebook, it doesn't fully erase cookies of Safari.
So that make it to not use Safari authentication method.
That leads Facebook login to be on app itself rather than safari.

And about twitter, ShareKit 2.0 uses iOS standard Twitter framework to log in/out from Twitter.
Users can sign in to Twitter using their account on Settings application of the iPhone.
When users connect to Twitter on their app, it uses registered account only and users can select their account from the list.

Is there any other solutions of these problems?
I'd like to know them, if any.

Thanks for SO and everybody.
Pei.